# storing a negative integer in signed char

Tags: c, char

I'm trying to get a function that stores integers in `char`. I need to use `char` rather than `int` because I need to use the question mark (`?`) to terminate my loop. However, I can't seem to make my code work. Here's my work:

```
int main() {
    signed char num;
    scanf("%c", &num);
    if (num!='?') {
        printf("%c\n", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I input a negative number (say, `-9`), I get the output:

```
-
```

I tried using the integer print symbol (`%d`) rather than `%c` when I was printing the values, as I saw on this question: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-assign-a-negative-number-to-a-char-variable-Why-or-why-not but makes everything I input junky. ie when I input `2`, it returns `50`.

I was told that `signed char` should do the thing here, but I'm not sure that's the case now.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do it like this. You need to first read the input as string (`fgets`) and then parse it  . You can make it relatively simple, depending on what kinds of bad inputs you want to handle

Comment: Do you know the ASCII code of "2"? Might be enlightening.

Comment: You cannot use `%c` to convert user input such as “-9” to a `signed char`. `%c` reads one character and puts the code for that character in the passed variable. Scan for a decimal numeral using `%d` with an `int`. Check the return value of `scanf`. If it is not 1, indicating 1 conversion and assignment was successfully completed, then scan using `%c` with `char`. If that produces a question mark (character literal `'?'`) in the `char`, then accept it as the user indicating termination. Otherwise, report an error to the user that they entered neither a decimal numeral nor a question mark.

Comment: Are you aware of the meaning of the return value of `scanf()`? It is mentioned in the docs https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf Reading up on it will allow you to try scanning for an integer (into an appropriate integer variable) and if it fails check for a character (scanned into a character variable) being equal to "?".

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information: What kind of input do you want to process? Do I understand right that you expect the user to enter either a number or a question mark? What is the allowed range for the numbers?

Comment: It's interesting that you say you must use `char` rather than `int` because you want to store a `?`.  Perhaps you are unaware that `'?'` is of type `int`.

Comment: aaa, What should happen if input is non-numeric and not `"?"`, like `"qwerty\n"`?

Comment: `-9` is two chars.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to scan an integer and at the same time scan a character like `?` you can do:

1. Try to scan an integer
2. If scan for integer fails, try to scan a char

Like

```
int num;
char c;
if (scanf("%d", &num) == 1)
{
    // Okay you got an integer.

    c = num;  // BUT... watch out for over/underflow !!!
}
else if (scanf("%c", &c) == 1)
{
    // Okay you got a char
    if (c == '?')
    {
        // You got your ?
    }
    else
    {
        // Some other char

        // Some kind of error handling... perhaps
        c = 0;
    }
}
else
{
    // Input error that can't be recovered
    exit(1);
}
```

See online example https://ideone.com/kTPE0M

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: The `scanf("%c", &c)` is used only after `scanf("%d, …)` has been tried, and that will have consumed leading white space.

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong format:

it has to be (but you will have to enter 63 instead of `?`):

```
      signed char num;
      scanf("%hhd", &num);
```

or

```
    char str[6];
    char num;
    fgets(str,5,stdin);
    if (str[0]!='?') {
        if(sscanf(str, "%hhd", &num) == 1)
            printf("%c\n", num);
        else {/* handle scanf error*/}
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. :) added some more

Comment: Minor: Off by 1. `fgets(str,6,stdin);` is OK.  Even better as `fgets(str,sizeof str,stdin);`.  I suspect "handle scanf" s/b "handle sscanf"

Comment: `it has to be (but you will have to enter 63 instead of ?):` hmmm... something seems to be missing in that sentence

Comment: There's no evidence the OP really wanted the integral (non-`?`) result limited to a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to do anything at all complicated, `scanf` is almost never the right tool for the job.

And, although it might not be obvious at first, the task "read a thing that's either an integer, or a question mark that indicates the end of the input" is definitely, in this sense, something that's too complicated for `scanf`.  There's no good format specifier for that kind of "thing".

The easiest thing is to read a line of *text* (using `fgets`, not `scanf`), then start trying to figure out what's in it — question mark, integer, or something else.  (What if the user types "`x`"?)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char line[512];
    int num;          /* note int not char */

    if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL)
         printf("end of file or error\n");
    else if(line[0] == '?')
         printf("end of input\n");
    else if(sscanf(line, "%d", &num) == 1)
         printf("numeric input: %d\n", num);
    else printf("unexpected input!\n");
}
```

Note that this program still isn't perfect: If the user, types, say, "`123x`", this program will say it saw numeric input, and won't notice or complain about the extra `x`.  Also, it only looks at the first character of the line to see if it's a `?`, so it will also accept things line `??` or `?Cat in the hat`.  (There are ways to fix both of those things, but they get rather elaborate, and are probably more trouble than they're worth for a simple exercise.)

See also [What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537)